# Make post on behalf of app to a user's profile

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-wall

Is there a way for the app (xyz) to post on a spcefic member's FB wall and and **not ALL** members of the applicaiton?   App xyz wants to post to Adam Smith's FB wall, "Adam Smith,  your score has been beaten."        My understanding is that only the member can self-post on their own wall and not the app.   The **objective** is tryinng to get the notifications flag in the notification box in the upper left hand corner of the fb page to appear when our notificaiton comes through. By having the member self-post, the flag will not appear.       So can an app xyz post on a particular member's wall without sending the post to all members?     If not, is there a way of "raising" the notification flag when a post is made on that members wall?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible via posts, but the Requests API allows for this; See App to User requests on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: Thanks Igy. Based on my interpretation,  to achieve my objective of sending a notification to one of my member’s FB notification jewel;  taking into consideration scenario #3 of the 3 types of scenarios a  user can send a request, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#user_to_user  “a user can send a request to another member, as long as the recipient is a member/downloaded the app, the sender and recipient do not need to be FB friends in order to post notifications.  I could set up a “dummy” FB profile for my app and my app dummy profile would send requests..continued nxt post

Comment: [continued post]      (i.e. “Igy, we need a new quarterback, your turn.”) to a particular user  and the recipient would receive a notification in their notification jewel?

Comment: That would be expressly against Facebook policy; but you should look at 'App to User' requests, where the app can send a notification saying something like 'new activity in [APP name]'

Comment: but app to user request wouldn't post to their wall or show up in the notification jewel. Am I correct?    My biggest objective is getting their instant attention and only way of clearly doing this is delivering a post to the notification jewel indicator show up.